# Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: measure-theory

For $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ with counting measure is $\mathcal{L}^1$ complete.
Let $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1$ such that  every $f_k$ is a sequence $(f^n_k)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Show that a sequence $f=(f^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ exists such that $f_k$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attention**: Since the functions $f_k$ are functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$, it is clearer to write $f_k(n)$ instead of $f_k^n$.

Let us prove the result.

Since $(f_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{N},\#)$ (where $\#$ is the counting measure), we have that, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is $M \in \mathbb{N}$, such that, if $r,s >M$ then
$$ \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |f_r(i) -f_s(i)| = \int |f_r -f_s| d\# < \varepsilon$$

So, for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is $M \in \mathbb{N}$, such that, if $r,s >M$
$$ |f_r(j) -f_s(j)| \leqslant \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |f_r(i) -f_s(i)| = \int |f_r -f_s| d\# < \varepsilon$$

So, for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, $(f_k(j))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence (in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). So,  for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $a_j$ such that  $(f_k(j))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a_j$.

Define $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), by $f(j)=a_j$, for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is clear that $f_k$ converges pointwise to $f$.